# Which KEY is used by Paypal so I can synchronize with my website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application with Paypal integration.

When a user makes a payment I send that payment to paypal and I wait for the info.

But I need to send a key to know which user made the payment.

What is the variable that I should send to paypal and have in my database to know which user made a specific payment?

And should I add the payment to my database with "unconfirmed" and then change the status when I receive the paypal confirmation or should I just add the payment on my database after i receive the notification?

Thank You
Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have local invoice records you can use the INVOICE parameter in API requests to include that ID in transactions.  That will then come back in IPN's and transaction details requests for that payment in the future.

You could also do the same thing with the CUSTOM parameter, which simply allows for 256 chars of anything you want.  Again, anything you send there will be available in IPN or transaction details later.

As for how to handle the status, that's completely up to you.  I personally like to go with the option of adding the pending order and then marking it complete when the payment finalizes.  That way I have data for orders that were never completed and I can look into why that might be.

Comment: Yes, that was my idea: to create the order on my database with a GUID as a KEY, the amount and the Status Pending. Then when I receive the confirmation I would find the record by KEY, confirm the amount and update the Status to Completed if that is the case.

Comment: I have my workflow created ... All I need is a PayPal form in my web site but that runs the payment behind the scenes in paypal website. What is that service?